# XMLHttpRequest file load error. What should the file format contain?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have taken a basic xml retrieval from the net, but I cannot reproduce it on my network drive.  I just want to test this out and make sure I can reproduce this before starting my small project.  My issue is on line 55 (xmlhttp.send();).  I get these errors.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Y:/BWI/cd_catalog.xml. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. Uncaught
>   NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to
>   load 'file:///Y:/BWI/cd_catalog.xml'.

I figured it has something to do with the formatting of the file load (file:///Y:/BWI/cd_catalog.xml).  What should the proper format be in order for this simple html page to read the file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,xx,i;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    txt="<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      txt=txt + "<tr>";
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
        {
        try
          {
          txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
          }
        }
      txt=txt + "</tr>";
      }
    txt=txt + "</table>";
    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML=txt;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txtCDInfo">
<button onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')">Get CD info</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScriuopt running on the file system has different security rules than the http protocol. You can run the browser to allow it, but it is better to run a local server. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/ or node or apache or any of the others.

Comment: [Download WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

> What should the proper format be in order for this simple html page to read the file?

It should be `http://` something. You need to run a webserver. You can't access file systems directly.